# Running thin server in production mode isn't loading my assets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, thin

When I load `thin` like so:

```
thin start -e production
```

and try to access one of my pages, I get this in the log output:

```
cache: [GET /] miss
cache: [GET /assets/main-bd1ef4b153740fb69fd615304b87ad0d.css] miss
cache: [GET /assets/jqModal-8fa734bf4f58524b2799abd73ab7d34f.css] miss
cache: [GET /assets/jquery-544665ba1d5b4f793290421aafed85c9.js] miss
cache: [GET /assets/application-00b97aa2429046c0c43802f07b756b46.js] miss
```

These files exist in my `assets` directory under `public`.

I've run this command also:

```
RALS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

I've tried just accessing the file `/public/assets/application.js` in the browser like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/application.js
```

Which gives me a 404 error (even though the file exists in `/public/assets` but the file can be read when I make a request to the file when the server is in development mode.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem exactly - that there's a cache miss? (which can be expected the first time you request the file), or is it that those files are not accessible at all? They _should_ be available at http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rails serving static files is turned off in production (`config/environments/production.rb`) by default:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

The Thin server is not configured to serve the static assets, and so requests to your assets are failing.

Comment: This is looking like the fix I need. I will mark this as the answer once I deploy to heroku and know for sure.

Comment: Is it advisable to use Thin as a server? The hosting company advised that and they have made a proxy towards thin. It works, but it might be not as fast I read somewhere. And Ryan, are you the guy from Spree? :-)

Comment: I would not use Thin in production. I would use either Unicorn or Puma. Yes, I am the Ryan guy who was previously from Spree, but now I work for LIFX.

Comment: I believe you can get better production speeds from Unicorn and Puma.